# Calling method in ParallelFor

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have one certain method `bool Method(Myobject Obj)` and I want to call him while I'm in `ParallelFor()` loop. Can I actually do that? Is this thread-safe or something like that? It feels like something wrong to call method like this.

Comment: Of course you can do that.  Whether it is thread-safe or not depends on what the method does.

Comment: Did you try it? Can you share your code? Was does `Method` do?

Comment: @Icepickle No, I have not tried yet to test it, just wanted to know if my object `Obj` can "mix" with another `Obj` from parallel process or something similar to that. I should say that inside this `Method` is nothing thread crossing, only `Obj` processing.

Comment: Oh dear, again downvoted, do we really hate newbies so much here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread safety is always decided based on context or specific case.
Let's say, that you have this:

```
public static bool Even(int i)
{
    return num % 2 == 0;  //true: even, false: odd
}

public static void ThreadSafe()
{
    bool[] arr = new bool[333];

    Parallel.For(0, arr.Length, index =>
    {
        arr[index] = Even(index);
    });
}
```

Now is it thread safe? Yes.
Each index of the array is assigning a value to one related index in arr.
Thus it can be done in parallel.
But what about now?

```
   public static void ThreadUnsafe()
   {
       bool[] arr = new bool[333];

       Parallel.For(0, arr.Length, index =>
       {
           arr[index] = Even(index);
           int index2 = (index + 1) < arr.Length ? (index + 1) : index;
           arr[index2] = Even(index);
       });
    }
```

With given index, we can assign two indexes in arr and some other thread can be writing to it as well. It is not thread-safe as we do not know, what will be the result.

Now you can see, that context in which a method is used can determine its thread safety as well.

Also, there are multiple types of thread safety.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is that I asked for. Gonna read about those types of safety now.